# Neo4j Cypher query for similarity calculation slow performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very new to Neo4j/Graph databases and trying to replicate tutorial from Cypher cookbook: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-similarity-calc.html

Random data set with 100 foods and 1500 persons, all persons are related to food through ATE relationship with "times" integer property. Food and Person are labeled and have properties "name" - which is indexed by auto-index

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ dbinfo -g "Primitive count"
{
  "NumberOfNodeIdsInUse": 1600,
  "NumberOfPropertyIdsInUse": 151600,
  "NumberOfRelationshipIdsInUse": 150000,
  "NumberOfRelationshipTypeIdsInUse": 1
}

neo4j-sh (?)$ index --indexes
Node indexes:
  node_auto_index
Relationship indexes:
  relationship_auto_index
```

Running modified query from cookbook in neo4j-shell never completes (probably because of too much nodes/relationships?):

```
EXPORT name="Florida Goyette"
MATCH (me:Person { name: {name}})-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you:Person)
WITH me,count(DISTINCT r1) AS H1,count(DISTINCT r2) AS H2,you
MATCH (me)-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you)
RETURN SUM((1-ABS(r1.times/H1-r2.times/H2))*(r1.times+r2.times)/(H1+H2)) AS similarity
LIMIT 100;
```

So I started to look how can I limit earlier to "first" 100 persons and came out with this:

```
EXPORT name="Florida Goyette"
MATCH (me:Person { name: {name} })-[r1:ATE]->(food)
WITH me, food
MATCH (food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you)
WHERE me <> you
WITH me, you
LIMIT 100
MATCH (me)-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you)
WITH me, count(DISTINCT r1) AS H1, count(DISTINCT r2) AS H2, you
MATCH (me)-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you)
WITH me, you, SUM((1-ABS(r1.times/H1-r2.times/H2))*(r1.times+r2.times)/(H1+H2)) AS similarity
RETURN me.name, you.name, similarity
ORDER BY similarity DESC;
```

But this query performs very poorly on warmed up cache

```
100 rows
16038 ms
```

Is there any chance to make such query to perform faster, for "real-time" usage?

**System and Neo4j**

Windows 7 (64-bit), Intel Core I7-2600K, 8GB RAM, Neo4j database on SSD drive.

Neo4j Community version: 2.1.0-M01 (also tested on 2.0.1 stable)

**neo4j-community.options**

```
 -Xmx2048m
 -Xms2048m
```

**neo4j.properties**

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=330M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=330M

node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=name
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=times
```

[Cypher dump of my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/op6298o3fubgwqh/test_dump.zip) (503kb zipped)

**PROFILE output**

```
ColumnFilter(symKeys=["similarity", "you", "you.name", "me", "me.name"], returnItemNames=["me.name", "you.name", "similarity"], _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
Sort(descr=["SortItem(similarity,false)"], _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
  Extract(symKeys=["me", "you", "similarity"], exprKeys=["me.name", "you.name"], _rows=100, _db_hits=200)
    ColumnFilter(symKeys=["me", "you", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEcb085cf5-8982-4a83-ba3d-9642de570c59"], returnItemNames=["me", "you", "similarity"], _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
      EagerAggregation(keys=["me", "you"], aggregates=["(INTERNAL_AGGREGATEcb085cf5-8982-4a83-ba3d-9642de570c59,Sum(Divide(Multiply(Subtract(Literal(1),AbsFunction(Subtract(Divide(Property(r1,times(1)),H1),Divide(Property(r2,times(1)),H2)))),Add(Property(r1,times(1)),Property(r2,times(1)))),Add(H1,H2))))"], _rows=100, _db_hits=40000)
        SimplePatternMatcher(g="(you)-['r2']-(food),(me)-['r1']-(food)", _rows=10000, _db_hits=0)
          ColumnFilter(symKeys=["me", "you", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE677cd11c-ae53-4d7b-8df6-732ffed28bbf", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEb5eb877c-de01-4e7a-9596-03cd94cfa47a"], returnItemNames=["me", "H1", "H2", "you"], _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
            EagerAggregation(keys=["me", "you"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE677cd11c-ae53-4d7b-8df6-732ffed28bbf,Distinct(Count(r1),r1))", "(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEb5eb877c-de01-4e7a-9596-03cd94cfa47a,Distinct(Count(r2),r2))"], _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
              SimplePatternMatcher(g="(you)-['r2']-(food),(me)-['r1']-(food)", _rows=10000, _db_hits=0)
                ColumnFilter(symKeys=["me", "food", "you", "r2"], returnItemNames=["me", "you"], _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
                  Slice(limit="Literal(100)", _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
                    Filter(pred="NOT(me == you)", _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
                      SimplePatternMatcher(g="(you)-['r2']-(food)", _rows=100, _db_hits=0)
                        ColumnFilter(symKeys=["food", "me", "r1"], returnItemNames=["me", "food"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
                          Filter(pred="Property(me,name(0)) == {name}", _rows=1,_db_hits=148901)
                            TraversalMatcher(start={"label": "Person", "producer": "NodeByLabel", "identifiers": ["me"]}, trail="(me)-[r1:ATE WHERE true AND true]->(food)", _rows=148901, _db_hits=148901)
```

Comment: **Edit:** [GraphGist](http://gist.neo4j.org/?84fba1eb09879db7f55e)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the same MATCHing multiple times. Does this work better?

```
EXPORT name="Florida Goyette"
MATCH (me:Person { name: {name}})-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you:Person)
WITH me,r1,r2,count(DISTINCT r1) AS H1,count(DISTINCT r2) AS H2,you
LIMIT 100 
RETURN SUM((1-ABS(r1.times/H1-r2.times/H2))*(r1.times+r2.times)/(H1+H2)) AS similarity;
```

Comment: Unfortunately no.

`1 row
361023 ms`

Comment: After setting proper indexes it returns now in 1400ms. But results are inaccurate.

Comment: Can you share the results?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong kind of index. Create a label index with

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

Check schema indices and constraints with

**neo4j-shell**

```
schema
schema ls -l :User
```

or

**neo4j-browser**

```
:schema 
:schema ls -l :User
```

There may be optimizations to do to the query, but start here.

Comment: Yep, the current version does find _all_ paths and filters afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I misread indexing docs and used "legacy" indexing. Will change that and try.

Answer (score 0):

1. On windows memory mapping is *inside* the heap. So increase your heap size to 4G.
2. You don't need the old auto-indexes but the new schema index like jjaderberg stated.
3. How many rows does this return?

.

```
MATCH (me:Person { name: {name}})-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you:Person) RETURN count(*)
```

and how many this:

```
MATCH (me:Person { name: {name}})-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you:Person)
WITH me,count(DISTINCT r1) AS H1,count(DISTINCT r2) AS H2,you
MATCH (me)-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you)
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

You can also avoid matching twice:

```
MATCH (me:Person { name: {name}})-[r1:ATE]->(food)<-[r2:ATE]-(you:Person)
WITH me,
     collect([r1,r2]) as rels, 
     count(DISTINCT r1) AS H1,
     count(DISTINCT r2) AS H2,
     you

RETURN me,you, 
       reduce(a=0,r in rels | 
              a + (1-ABS(r[0].times/H1-r[1].times/H2))*
                  (r[0].times+r[1].times)
                  /(H1+H2) as similarity
```

Btw. it would be awesome if you created a [GraphGist](http://gist.neo4j.org) with your domain, use-cases and some sample data !!

Comment: I've set -Xmx and -Xms to 3072m ( currently on my laptop ). Windows "Resource manager" shows Commit 3.4GB and Working set 1.3GB for neo4j-community.exe

I changed indexing as @jjaderberg suggested.

First query returns 149900 rows in 700ms (after first run).
Second query returns 149000 rows in 140588ms (after first run).

I can't get your third query to work, I get syntax exception

`(SyntaxException: Invalid input '.': expected whitespace)
 a + (1-ABS(r[0].times/H1-r[1].times/H2))*"`

Error pointed in: r[0].times

Comment: I created [GraphGist](http://gist.neo4j.org/?84fba1eb09879db7f55e) is this what you had in mind?